# How To Query A Remote Index From Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, full-text-search

I have a machine running Windows 2008 Server using the built-in Windows Indexing functionality.  I have a separate machine running Windows 8.  I need to query the Windows 2008 index from the Windows 8 machine.  I used to be able to do this using the MSIDXS provider but this is no longer in option in Windows 8.

Is there a new way to deal with this scenario?  My internet searches haven't turned up much.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store apps use contracts and extensions to enable communications between apps and between an app and Windows. More info on the subject [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464906.aspx). I haven't worked with MSIDXS provider, but from what you described, you will not be able to access the data residing on a server directly as you would before.

One option is to expose the index data as a service to your Windows Store app. This is probably not optimized for your case, but it is a general approach to consider when you need to communicate with resources outside of your Windows Store app.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  This is not a Windows Store app.  I am running Windows 8 Pro on a desktop and this is a regular C#.NET application.

Your an idea for a service should work but I was more interested in a way to write a direct query like I am currently running.  Thanks though.